# Woocommerce - add to cart button and quantity in product list on category page

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have a custom product list on a specific category page.

It looks like this:

[Product list category page with missing quantity selection and add to cart button at end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUSdb.jpg)

I have been using the below in functions.php and it has worked fine. Since the last update of WooCommerce it no longer works. The add to cart buttons and quantity fields are not showing anymore.

I get no errors and the fields where the qty and button html goes are blank when I check the html for the page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );

function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {


    $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $post_id = 'product_cat_'.$term_id;
    $wk_cat_value = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_cat_template', true);

    // Only for this product category

    if ($wk_cat_value == 1 && is_product_category()) 

    {

        if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) 

        {
            $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
            $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
            $html .= '</form>';


        }   
         return $html;
    }


}
```

**This line is a checkbox I added to the category page to specify if the current category is to use the custom template:
$wk_cat_value = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_cat_template', true);**

Template version Woocommerce files were 2.0.0.
Updated versions are 3.4.0.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add exact versions of woocommerce you've been using before and after update. Also you should be more specific about what "no longer works" mean. Is there some error, does it produce unexpected results or is your function not called at all?

Comment: Cheers Michael.

Have added more info.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
function wk_add_to_cart() {

    $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $post_id = 'product_cat_'.$term_id;
    // $wk_cat_value is a flag added to this specific category to decide whether or not the add to cart should be added
    $wk_cat_value = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_cat_template', true);    

    global $product;

    if ($wk_cat_value == 1 && is_product_category()) {                

        if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() )  {

        echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        echo  woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        echo  '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        echo  '</form>';

       }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','wk_add_to_cart');
```

Hope that helps.